# Homology of manifolds

Tags: manifolds, homology-cohomology

Does it hold that $H_n(M) \cong \mathbb Z$ if $M$ is an $n$-manifold? I know that it is true for relative homology $H_n (M, M-p)$.

Answer (score 2):

If the manifold is compact without boundary (i.e., "closed"), as well as connected, and you use $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients in homology, then the isomorphism you want will hold if and only if $M$ is orientable.

Comment: You also need connectedness there (and nonemptyness, I suppose).

Comment: Good point, thanks.

Comment: Thank you! Could you give me any reference to where I could read a proof of this?

Comment: I recall that the textbook by Greenberg and Harper is an eminently readable one.  If you can't find the precise reference I can try to look it up.

Comment: It's on page 236 of Hatcher's book.

Answer (score 1):

It is true precisely when M is orientable; if there is a top-dimensional cycle, i.e., if we can orient M to get a top cycle C, then C cannot bound, because there are no (n+1)-cycles--remember than $|\partial M^n|$=$n-1$. If your manifold is not orientable, then we cannot find any coherent n-cycle, and we conclude the homology is zero.